# Metal render producing odd race condition

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, metal, metalkit

I turned on the thread sanitizer in Xcode 9.4.1 and now I'm getting an odd race condition warning on my rotating buffer (of size up to 2).  I would have thought that proper semaphore usage here would have eliminated this issue.  I should mention that this buffer comes from the output of another render encode in a separate 'first' `MTKView`. I have a semaphore that I've initialized via `dispatch_semaphore_create(1)` in the second downstream view.

In my first `MTKView` I grab the rendered texture as follows after I've committed it, and then enqueue it into the downstream buffer using that downstream view's semaphore:

```
[commandBuffer presentDrawable:self.currentDrawable];
[commandBuffer commit];
//[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted]; // (doesn't matter if this is in or out)
...
id obj = [self.renderedQueue firstObject];
for (MonitorMTKView *v in self.downstreamOutputs) {
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(v.bufferSemaphore,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   [v.textureQueue addObject:inputTexture];
   if ([v.textureQueue count]>2)
      [v.textureQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
   dispatch_semaphore_signal(v.bufferSemaphore);
}
```

Now onto the render loop in my downstream `MTKView`.  I commit the command buffer and I have this completion handler:

```
__block __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer) {
   dispatch_semaphore_wait(weakSelf.bufferSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   id obj = [weakSelf.textureQueue firstObject];

**// thread sanitizer issue on this next line of code "Race on a library object detected" **
   [weakSelf.textureQueue removeObject:obj];

   dispatch_semaphore_signal(weakSelf.bufferSemaphore);
}
```

Why the race condition around what is semaphore-protected? **Is there something I'm doing horribly wrong?**. The buffer itself isn't GPU-based, so there can't be interference there.

One line of thinking is to triple-buffer this, but that doesn't alleviate the issue, so I don't think its GPU interference.

Comment: Are you sure that each object's `textureQueue` is unique and private to itself? Do you ever pass that array into other code?

Comment: Ken... the textureQueue referenced in both these cases is a property on the downstream MTKView only.   The original MTKView loads up the queue with the resulting texture of its encoder (right at the tail end of its draw call), and the downstream queue consumes the texture at the beginning of its draw call and discards in its drawing completion hander.  In all cases, altering the queue is semaphore-protected which is why the race condition is so troubling.  Thanks for trying to help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Metal documentation indicates that you should be using 3 buffers in order to avoid race conditions between filling the buffers and passing to the GPU.

Comment: I've implemented triple buffering but Xcode's commentary on this purported 'race condition' is troubling... with semaphores being a specific solution to avoid such issues.